# PDO MySql: Can a single query find all the people that live in each region?

Tags: mysql

PDO MySql: Can a single query find all the items (from items table) that are in each region (from reports table where 'region' is a column that contains duplicates)?

reports table:

```
|  id  |  region  |  date  |  notes  |
|   1  |  central |  June  |  blah   |
|   2  |   mid    |  May   |  foo    |
|   3  |  central |  Aug   |  bar    |
```

items table

```
| id  |  reportid  |  name  |
|  1  |    3       | widget | 
|  2  |    1       | gadget | 
|  3  |    3       | dodad  | 
|  4  |    2       | thingy |
```

Comment: The central region has gadget, widget and dodad, the mid region has thingy.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select distinct r.region, group_concat(i.name) items
from reports r 
join items i on r.id = i.reportid
group by r.region;
```

Assuming you want one field with a list of items per region. If you want to list each region with each item associated to it, you can skip the group by and the group concat.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll give it a try.